# de-serialze a byte[] that was serialzed with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a `byte[]` that was serialized with the following code:

```
// Save an object out to the disk
public static void SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize, String filename)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filename);

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

problem is the data serialized looks like this:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAAFACAIAAAANimYEAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx......
```

when it gets stored in my database it looks like this:

```
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000F00000014008020000000D8A660400000001......
```

What is the difference, and how can I get the data from the disk back into a `byte[]`?

---

Note: the data is a `Bitmap` formatted as a png like this:

```
public byte[] ImageAsBytes
{
    get
    {
        if (_image != null)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            _image .Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    set
    {

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(value);
        _image = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAAFACAIAAAANimYEAAAAA...
```

is base64 encoded representation of the binary data.

```
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000F000000140080...
```

is hexadecimal.

To get the data back from the disk use XmlSerializer and deserialize it back to the original object:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string filename)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(filename))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

But if you only have the base64 string representation you could use the [FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) method:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String("iVBORw0KGgoAAANimYEAAAAA...");
```

Remark: make sure you always dispose disposable resources such as streams and text readers and writers. This doesn't seem to be the case in your `SerializeObject<T>` method nor in the getter and setter of the `ImageAsBytes` property.

Comment: You sir, are awesome!  As for disposable stuff, I am going to ask another question on that, because I have never really understood it.